# uinavigationcontroller question

Tags: iphone

i have the below code

```
UINavigationController *sample = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newcontact];
```

does newcontactview get reatined  when i do the above?

Comment: The question is not clear.  What do you mean by "reatined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all controllers added to navigation controller stack (including root controller) are retained by UINavigationController

Comment: how about when we do [self presentmodalviewcontroller], do the controller that is presented get retained?